# extract month number from sysdate without 0 in R

Tags: r, date, datetime

I am trying to get the current month numbers for a code in R through this -

```
currentDate<-Sys.Date()
month_num <- format(Sys.Date(),"%m")
```

The output I am getting is "03" for today(28/03/2018)
Is there a way that I can get 3 instead ?
Such as Jan:1 , Feb : 2 and so on Dec: 12 
(without hard-coding it)

Comment: You can use "as.numeric" function:

as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(), "%m"))

Comment: Or `as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$mon+1`

Comment: @Ika8 Thanks, that works :)

Answer (score 2):

The `lubridate` package has a function called `month` that will do what you want

```
library(lubridate)
month(currentDate)
```